# Remove virtual devices from genymotion

Tags: android, linux, genymotion

My pc had 20GB space before installing genymotion.
To get more space, I deleted the genymotion folder. But, I think there is virtual devices data because I didn't delete the virtual devices before deleting the folder.

Does anyone know how to remove the virtual devices data from my pc?

Answer (score 0):

You need to remove the `%LOCALAPPDATA%\Genymobile` directory